# Is there a way to initialize the increased memory with a demanding page?

Tags: c, memory, out-of-memory

I am using shared memory in Linux and I have some questions.

Since `shmat` accesses shared memory and uses memory, a "*demanding page*" is activated and memory is increased each time the pointer of shared memory is moved.

However, this is a problem because the memory capacity is considerably large.

So, is there a way to save memory like freeing the memory that you have read and transferred before moving the pointer?

The pseudo code is shown below.

```
My_struct *mem = NULL; // The structure size is 4K.

// shmat(...);
// For example, `VmRSS` was 10K. However, each iteration increases by 4K. (I know this is due to the `demand page`.)
// This is because the size of `My_struct` is 4K.
for (i=0; i<10000; i++)
{
  printf("%s\n", mem[i].name); // Here, the memory usage increases every time it is repeated.
  sleep(1); // It's just a pause to check VmRSS.

  // If I run the loop 10,000 times, I need about 40M of memory. 
  // (In real world, it is dying because of OOM in loop)
}
shmdt(mem);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "moving the pointer"?

Comment: As in the pseudo code, this means moving the position of `mem` in the loop and referencing the next memory location.

Comment: Also, when you detach some shared memory (with `shmdt`) you effectively mark the memory as available to the system. The operating system may keep the memory mapped to your process though, making it seem like you have a memory leak. But those pages are free for the operating system to map to another process when it needs to. Seeing them as a leak is a false positive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the reply. Before `shmdt`, I want to remove the accumulated memory due to `demanding page`. `shmdt` is done outside the loop. The problem is that the application dies due to a lack of memory during the loop.

Comment: So you are "allocating" (mapping) memory inside a loop? That is generally a recipe for disaster. Unless you need *all* the mapped memory after the loop, then unmap (`shmdt`) the pages in the loop once you're done with them. *And* if you "need" all the mapped memory after the loop, then perhaps you should rethink your design, since it's clearly not working well?

Comment: And to nitpick, I think you mean [*demand paging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) and not "demanding page"?

Comment: Yes. `Demand paging`. And I have not allocated any memory in the loop. Simply moving memory for `printf` will increase memory usage. Memory growth was verified by `VmRSS` at `/proc/pid/status`. I really only moved `mem[i]`. In my opinion, whenever you read a huge memory area accessed by shmat, it seems that memory is increasing due to the `demand page`.

Comment: I think it's time you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. Because it's really hard to understand what you mean by "moving memory". *How* do you "allocate" the shared memory? What do you really do? And as long as you don't go out of bounds or otherwise do something wrong or have some UB, I don't see it as a problem. If you ask the system for X bytes of memory, and the system gives you that, why would it be a problem?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that memory management comes for free. In a non-shm case, you could theoretically use `realloc` to in the fly while you run through the loop to release the elements you have already worked on - with horrendous performance. The same would work with shm page-wise, and even more horrendous performance.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I modified the pseudo code. "Moving memory" means calling mem[0], mem[1], mem[2], and so on.
For example, my system has only 40M of memory. At this time, if I loop the loop about 8,000 times, I run out of memory.
But I want to end the loop. Again, there is no malloc in the loop. Within the pseudocode, the loop statement is the same as the actual code.

Comment: `My_struct *mem = NULL;` What is *my_struct*?

Comment: @wildplasser It's just a simple structure that does not contain pointers.